# Change value by two functions

Tags: javascript

I have functions which change value variable `totalTime`.
When I use first func value equals `189 - 50` (139).
After using second func I want to receive `current value - 8` (131) but I have `189 - 8`.
What am I doing wrong?

```js
let totalTime = 189;  // *

function calcTime(){

  let hours     = Math.trunc(totalTime/60);
  let minutes   = totalTime % 60;
  let formatted = hours + 'h ' + minutes + 'm';
  
  fullTimeDefault.innerHTML = formatted;
}

function workTimeDecrease() {
  if(valueElem[0]) {
    if (+valueElem[0].innerHTML === 15) {
      return false
    } else{
      valueElem[0].innerHTML = parseInt(valueElem[0].innerHTML, 10) - step;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < barElem.length; i++) {
      barElem[i].style.width = parseInt(valueElem[0].innerHTML, 10) + '%';
    }
    totalTime -= 50 // (1!)
  }
}

function shortBreakDecrease() {
  if(valueElem[2]) {
    if (+valueElem[2].innerHTML === 3) {
      return false
    } else {
      valueElem[2].innerHTML = parseInt(valueElem[2].innerHTML, 10) - step;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < barElem2.length; i++) {
      barElem2[i].style.width = parseInt(valueElem[2].innerHTML, 10) + '%';
    }
    totalTime -= 8  // (2!)
  }
}

elem.onclick = function(event) {
      
      if (event.target.closest('.down-time')) {
        workTimeDecrease();
        calcTime();
      } else if (event.target.closest('.up-time')) {
        workTimeIncrease();
        calcTime();
      }

      if (event.target.closest('.down-short-break')) {
        shortBreakDecrease();
        calcTime();
      } else if (event.target.closest('.up-short-break')) {
        shortBreakIncrease();
        calcTime();
      }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Why are you talking about 189 + 50 and then + 8 when in your code we see `totalTime -= 50` and `totalTime -= 8` ? Also should we ignore the logic before `totalTime -= …` I mean all the ifs

Comment: What does the console say when your functions run? There may be a runtime error causing your function to `throw` an error before it reaches the `totalTime -= 8` part. Also be wary of where you're declaring your variables; `var`, etc tie the variable to a [scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp).

Comment: Where/how are you using the value of  totalTime  ? Nothing obviously wrong with what you have shown us, but it poses more questions than it answers

Answer (score 0):

My thoughts are that this line isn't assigning totalTime to your output, though it is being modified internally (also "step" is defined nowhere)

```
valueElem[0].innerHTML = parseInt(valueElem[0].innerHTML, 10) - step;
```

Maybe if you pass in step as 50 then 8 in the 2 calls (change headers to take as parameter):

```
function workTimeDecrease(int step) {
function shortBreakDecrease(int step) { ...
```

Change:

```
valueElem[0].innerHTML = parseInt(valueElem[0].innerHTML, 10) - step;
...
valueElem[2].innerHTML = parseInt(valueElem[0].innerHTML, 10) - step;
```

To:

```
valueElem[0].innerHTML = totalTime - step;
...
valueElem[2].innerHTML = totalTime - step;
```

And change both totalTime assignemts to:

```
totalTime -= step;
```

You could also do an alert or log to console right after totalTime assignment to make sure that's not the problem (or all over, helps to check values - I use those extensively for debugging, sometimes every single line).